# Uv map vertex = mesh vertex

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

My game engine ask me to create some specific Uv map.
I need to have the same number of vertex in the mesh and in the Uv map.

Creating seams and unwraping always create double in the Uv map.
To fix this, i have to select my seams, mark the seams, split the edges then unwrap.
This way, i create double in the mesh as well and it's working for my game engine.
But, when i use an object found on the web and i want to keep it's original Uv map, i have to work hard to find the seams and split the edge.

Question is, is there a way to delete the double edge in the Uvmap.
The final result might look bad in blender, but will look perfect in my game.

Thanks

Comment: Finding seams in the mesh might be easier by selecting one edge marked as seam in Edge Select mode and selecting similar via `Shift`+`G` > *Seam*.

Comment: wow i've search a lot to find this feature.

Answer (score -1):

You can merge the selected vertices by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and selecting *Weld* or *Remove Doubles*

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to the question.